# boostrap grid - 1 column in desktop and 2 in mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want it to be like this
[design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0VSK.png)
Thanks for the help

this is my code, I've tried it in fiddle and it's working but I wanted to be sure that it's the correct way to do it.

```
    <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">IMAGE </div>
            <div class=" col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">TEXT </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: if it's working in the fiddle then why post here?

Comment: Generally on SO, questions are for a specific problem you encounter and not to gain an opinion on if it's the right or wrong way. Try [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for that.

Comment: Accept an answer so that others know the question is resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct if it's inside a `container` or `container-fluid`. Follow the [Bootstrap docs for guidance](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Comment: So then what is your question?? You asked if it was correct and the code you posted doesn't show a container.

Comment: I wanted to know if the my code was right... I am new to bootstrap and sometimes things works without being right and thats why I asked.

Comment: Thanks for the help!